# yaml c++ dll under visual studio

Tags: yaml-cpp

I'm trying to create dll with 'yaml-cpp-0.3.0' under Visual Studio 8 2005 and getting linking error for 'INSTALL', 'run-tests'

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl YAML::operator>>(class YAML::Node const &,class YAML::Binary &)" (??5YAML@@YAXABVNode@0@AAVBinary@0@@Z) referenced in function "public: class YAML::Binary const __thiscall YAML::Node::to(void)const " (??$to@VBinary@YAML@@@Node@YAML@@QBE?BVBinary@1@XZ) parsertests.obj
>
> Error  2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals ....\yaml-cpp_dll\build\test\Debug\run-tests.exe    1

using the general steps mentioned by the user at http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=88

1. cd yaml-cpp for 'yaml-cpp-0.3.0'
2. mkdir build
3. cd build
4. cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -G "Visual Studio 8 2005" ..

Looking for help how to fix this.  Any inputs is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I filed an issue report (http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=152), and you can follow its progress. I'll try to get to it this week.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same linking error with Visual Studio 9 2008. The problem is that the >> operator declared in binary.h is not exported. After having done the following modifications in binary.h everything worked fine:

```
#include "yaml-cpp/dll.h"  // add a new include to have YAML_CPP_API defined

...

// add the missing YAML_CPP_API
YAML_CPP_API void operator >> (const Node& node, Binary& binary);
```